# Standard deviation a sample of compiling times in Android

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

For me thesis I have a sample of compiling times in Android, however, some people says the standard deviation is calculated by this method: $$\sqrt{\frac{\sum (x-\bar x)^2}{(n-1)}}.$$
Other methods divide by the # of tests. What is the difference between the two? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

The difference is whether you would like to use a biased (with $n$) or non-biased (with $n-1$) estimator. Please see [Wiki on unbiased estimation of standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation) for detailed info.